# mouse cursor blocks descriptions

Tags: windows-10

this happened because I enlarged the cursor, so now the relative space between any description and the cursor is not nearly enough, and so a good chunk of it is blocked.
who ever still don't understand what I mean can hover with their cursor any bottom in their browser and see the description box or the meta text.
[Mouse over description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeiWL.png)

so my question is, is there a way to fix it?

I'm using Windows 10 and Firefox

Comment: A screenshot of the problem would ensure that we are looking at the same thing you are trying to describe

Comment: No, there isn't. You can perhaps create your own cursor that will have a squashed shape, if you want to get fancy. But it would be simpler to use a smaller cursor.